# Is there any difference between theoretical and mathematical?

Tags: computer-science, terminology

In computer science, is there any difference in usage of the terms: theoretical, mathematical?

If yes, which is more broader?

Context: If my supervisor says *focus on theoretical aspects of the paper*  and *focus on mathematical aspects of the paper*. Should I interpret as same?

Comment: The terms are used differently in different contexts. Please include more context.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Is it okay now?

Comment: If you provide some details about the paper, then I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: As someone in computer science you shouldn't miss the fourth option with regards to subsets, that neither is included in the other.

Comment: @mlk mathematics < computer science < theoretical computer science, maybe...

Comment: @hanugm Better but still not enough context. You probably would need to present details from your paper, but then the question is too specific. My recommendation would be to ask your supervisor.

Comment: Questions about what you supervisor told you: ask your supervisor.

Comment: @user2768 For some definition of the different fields surely. But definitely not in the implicit definition of mathematics that is used when talking about "mathematical aspects of the paper".

Answer (score 3):

Theoretical and mathematical: **They're different**. Mathematical aspects are the mathematical parts, whereas theoretical aspects are the fundamental computer science parts. E.g., computational complexity is theoretical computer science, whereas statistical analysis is mathematical.

That said, **it may depend on the context**. Ask your advisor for clarity.

Ask your advisor for clarity whenever you don't understand, or, at least, mention that you don't understand and that you'll look into the details later, possibly asking for direction on where to look.

Comment: Some years ago, I wrote a proof that a proposed cache coherence protocol would not deadlock. That was applied, not theoretical, computer science. It was also mathematical.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Surely you proved the result in a theoretical model? (I appreciate that terminology is blurry. I think context generally gives way to distinct usage of terms.)

Answer (score 3):

This question is relevant to more than just computer science, so here's a take on it from an economist's perspective, that may still be relevant to other fields.

> ... a growing feeling in the later years of my work at the subject that a good mathematical theorem dealing with economic hypotheses was very unlikely to be good economics: and I went more and more on the rules - (1) Use mathematics as a shorthand language, rather than an engine of inquiry. (2) Keep to them till you have done. (3) Translate into English. (4) Then illustrate by examples that are important in real life. (5) Burn the mathematics. (6) If you can't succeed in (4), burn (3). This last I did often.
>
> Alfred Marshall, 1906

This quote (which is amusing in the light of where modern economics has gone), strongly suggests that *theory* is some meta level above *mathematics*, and that mathematics is in fact often used to support theories.  I feel like this generalizes to other fields, even mathematics itself.  After all, if a mathematical theory [remains unproven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics), what is it based on?  Of course, I'm being sloppy with my language here, and I believe *conjecture* would be a more technically accurate term.  But when your hypothetical advisor says to "focus more on the theoretical aspects" I believe they're probably using the term theory more in a colloquial sense.  I'm not involved in theoretical computer science, but there appears to be [similar topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_computer_science) there.

So in short, I feel like theory may include mathematics, or non mathematics, like narrative reasoning or formal logic, and is thus broader.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your supervisor is using both words fairly loosely, and that you should think about them in the context of what you are working on specifically.

"Theoretical" parts of the paper might refer to some grounding mathematical theory, but also might just be in contrast to an experimental part. For example, if you are writing a paper about computer systems, the theoretical part might be where you explain your model of what is going on abstractly, as opposed to when you do experiments to probe and develop that understanding. In this case it does not necessarily involve mathematics, but probably is a bit abstracted from the concrete cases considered in the experiments.

"Mathematical" parts of the paper might again relate to the abstract theory, but could also mean where you apply statistical analysis to experimental data.

So you should take these comments in the light of the actual topic and paper at hand. In terms of what your supervisor is trying to communicate, I would check with them to confirm, but it sounds like they are trying to direct your attention *towards* the chunk of the paper that's to do with the formal setting of the research, and *away* from thinking (for now) about other aspects of the paper, such as experiments, literature review, formatting, etc.